# Cannot find this 6 pin IC 362J38

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have a power brick I'm trying to repair but have been unable to locate a 6 pin IC 362J38 that I suspect is the issue. No other faults found except the fuse after going over the board 3 times. No visual clues. All e caps, mosfets removed & checked. Opto is good.  Not sure what the IC function is, either pwm or a regulator, open to suggestion. It is located on the hot side. I'm trying to find out if there is a substitute IC -  please answer only if you are familiar with these type of 'cheap' SMPS units. Just asking for help.

**Close-up** 
[image: close_up]

**Full board** 
[image: full board]

---

Zoom in on pic if you need more detail. After having a conversation with 2 qualified techs (far more experience with these than me) no other faults detected, it was suggested that an IC probably blew. The unit was accidentally shorted on the output side and stopped working. IC on secondary was replaced to no avail. Only other fault was fuse. Inductors were not tested.

Comment: if you do not know what it is, then why do you susoect that it is faulty? ... also, why did you not include a cleseup view of the IC and its surrounding components?

Comment: Can you provide a clearer picture of the part itself, from much closer.

Comment: Looking at that image I see a whole bunch of things that could be causing issues. The chip you circled doesn't *seem* bad to my eye (its traces on the other hand...). Over all the rework looks pretty poor IMO. (Duplicating my comment here since I don't the the answer it's on will last much longer.)

Comment: I can't read the part number of the IC (need closer image!), but the terminal connected to R12 looks like it has a 'dry' (cracked) solder joint. The one to the left of it might too.

Comment: Also the right-hand pad above D7 looks a bit dodgy as do the three pads to its right.  The big scratch running down and to the left below R12 looks a bit worrisome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it that chip is actually marked `362J35`.  Going by [this](https://m.1688.com/offer/523358693495.html) it's probably some kind of buck regulator.  Unfortunately I don't think you'll be able to find a replacement anywhere but the Shenzhen market.

Comment: Actually, it is 362J38 under my scope. I think you're right, only going to find it in a Shenzhen marketplace not online, probably proprietary, unfortunately. I was hoping to find a substitute IC if I could determine it's function but that's a wild guess for me. These things are so cheap it really doesn't pay to work on them but it was a personal challenge and I was hoping someone with more skill and experience would have a solution, I just thought I would ask the forum - thanks.

Comment: @RichL Personally I'd check those dodgy looking traces and pads with a continuity tester.